# Fuzzy Vlookup to Display All Matched Results Across a Single Row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I'm aware that vlookup only returns one result, but I'm looking for a way to search across 2 columns and return all results that match this query:

```
SUBSTITUTE("*"&C2&"*"," ","*")
```

This way it returns similar matches as well. I'm able to return the first match (through a vlookup), but I need to return *all* matches and display them across a row.

If it would create an array, I could display the first match in the row with the first element in the array, display the second match with the second element.. and so on.

VBA so far:

```
Function Occur(text, occurence, column_to_check)
  newarray = Split(text, " ")

  Dim temp As New Collection
  Dim intX As Integer

   For i = 1 To 90000
   intX = 1
        For j = 0 To Len(newarray)
             If Not InStr(Range(column_to_check + i).Value, newarray(j)) Then
                intX = 0
             End If
        Next j
        Exit For
        If intX = 1 Then
            temp.Add (Cells(i, column_to_check))
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could just build the array in a `For...Next` loop and check whether cell value `Like Range(C2).Value`?

Comment: @DavidZemens I have no problem printing out the array. I'm more interested in how to create the array.

Comment: Also, assuming you mean "how to populate the array"...

Comment: not sure if you specifically want a VBA way, but you can do this with array formulae as well (though it does run slowly if you have many thousands of rows)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey There are 90,000 rows to check and 2 columns. I've attempted an array formulae before using INDEX and SMALL, but the substitution along with the 2 columns always causes an error. How would you suggest accomplishing it this way?

Comment: With 90,000 rows? I wouldnt! It would take 30 seconds or more to calculate...! VBA is the way to go, as unlike array formulae you can programme it in the knowledge of needing the data in the future, whereas array formulae kind of 'start again' for each iteration of the VLOOKUP/MATCH and you would get an O(n+(n-1)+(n-2)..0) problem.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Any recommended vba searching algorithm (that would populate an array with every match) to implement across any number of columns/rows for this "fuzzy match" then?

Comment: @TomWall just so i understand the main question correctly, you have a single value that you want to do a 'fuzzy' match on across the cells in two columns and return an array with each cell that matches?

Comment: **PUT YOUR CODE IN THE QUESTION IT IS IMPOSSIBLE TO READ IT IN THE COMMENTS.**

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Exactly. And the fuzzy match would work where if I were to type in "angry birds," the array would contain all cells that contain "angry" and "birds" somewhere in them. (for instance ipad_app_angry_birds would be returned)

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to match, also. You are looking to match anything that contains the substring value from `C2`?  And then also why are you substituting spaces/asterisks?

Comment: @TomWall oh, so if the cell has *any* word that you are looking for within any portion of it you want it to match? So, looking for "there is no spoon" within "None shall pass!" would be a match?

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry about that. Posted.

The substitution is done because the results have to contain _all_ the strings in C2 somewhere in the cell.

Example:

If C2 contains "angry birds", then here are a few cells that might be returned:

"ipad_angry_birds"
"Angry Birds Game"
"Birds_rovio_angry_"

Comment: @Cor_Blimey No, because _all_ the separate words have to be contained in the cell. See above comment to David for another example. Lovin' your example though.

Comment: ah ok, will post something in a few mins

Comment: What if it will contain something like "The birds are angry"? Should that also match?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can either use it as an array formulae selecting a reasonable number of cells to display the result, or use it in code and dump to the worksheet in whatever fashion you like.

It accepts a single string to search for (which it splits and tests each word within the single string), then a Param Array of strings, ranges or arrays to search in. It returns an array of matches so you can either use it as an array formula or use in code as any other array.

Usage examples:

- `=GetAllMatches("two three",A1:A5)` example with single contiguous range
- `=GetAllMatches("two three",A1,A3:A20,B5:B8,D1)` 'example with non-contiguous cells
- `=GetAllMatches("two three",{"one two","three two","one two three"})` example with array
- `=GetAllMatches("two three","one two","one","three two","one two three")` example with strings
- `For each match in GetAllMatches(blah,blahblah):Debug.Print match:Next match` example of use in code instead of a formula

You may have to tweak to taste but I have commented what it is doing in the code.

Code example:

```
Public Function GetAllMatches(searchFor As String, ParamArray searchWithin()) As Variant

    'I use a ParamArray to handle the case of wanting to pass in non-contiguous ranges to search other
    'e.g. Blah(A1,A2,A3,C4:C10,E5)
    'nice little feature of Excel formulae :)

    Dim searchRange, arr, ele, searchComponents
    Dim i As Long
    Dim results As Collection
    Dim area As Range
    Set results = New Collection

    'generate words to test
    searchComponents = Split(searchFor, " ")

    For Each searchRange In searchWithin
        If TypeOf searchRange Is Range Then 'range (we test to handle user passing in arrays)
            For Each area In searchRange.Areas 'we enumerate to handle multi-area ranges
                arr = area.Value
                If VarType(arr) < vbArray Then 'we test to handle single cell areas
                    If isMatch(arr, searchComponents) Then results.Add arr 'is a match so add to results
                Else 'is an array, so enumerate
                    For Each ele In arr
                        If isMatch(ele, searchComponents) Then results.Add ele  'is a match so add to results
                    Next ele
                End If
            Next area
        Else
            Select Case VarType(searchRange)
                Case Is > vbArray 'user passed in an array not a range
                    For Each ele In searchRange 'enumerate, not iterate, to handle multiple dimensions etc
                        If isMatch(ele, searchComponents) Then results.Add ele  'is a match so add to results
                    Next ele
                Case vbString
                    If isMatch(searchRange, searchComponents) Then results.Add searchRange  'is a match so add to results
                Case Else 'no idea - return an error then fail fast (suppressed if called by an excel formula so ok)
                    GetAllMatches = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrRef)
                    Err.Raise 1, "GetAllMatches", "Invalid Argument"
            End Select
        End If
    Next searchRange

    'Process Results
    If results.Count = 0 Then 'no matches
        GetAllMatches = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrNA) 'return #N/A
    Else
        'process results into an array
        ReDim arr(0 To results.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i) = results(i + 1)
        Next i
        GetAllMatches = arr 'Return the array of matches
    End If
End Function
Private Function isMatch(ByRef searchIn, ByRef searchComponents) As Boolean
    Dim ele
    For Each ele In searchComponents
        If Not (InStr(1, searchIn, ele, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ele
    isMatch = True
End Function
```

Example spreadsheet:

```
one                  
one two         
one two three           
one three two           
four three one two
```

results:
`one two three` `one three two` `four three one two`

Comment: Most of the code is 'fluff' to allow it to cope with a variety of stuff to look over. I re-use parts of this fluff quite a lot myself so I just copied parts over. It allows the UDFs to handle most of the things users expect as 'standard' from many built-in Excel formulae like the "," union operator and support for array formulae. The special bits for this - like the string Split() and the core 'matching' testing in 'isMatch' function - is very much like David Zemens' approac which deserves a +1 for sure for a good recommended principle / approach. Glad it helps.

Comment: Hey so I've got another question. I've been using this for a while, and it's been working great but I'd like to make a change. I'd like it to always return something from a certain column. So if the array includes all of column A and B, and finds a match on B50, then I'd want it to return B50. But, if it finds a match on A50, then I'd want it to return B50 instead of A50. This way it always returns 'B' and the row number it's found on. Would you happen to have some input on how to alter your code in order to provide this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a scripting dictionary and some array/range manipulation. I tested this on about 30,000 rows and it returned about 10,000 matches faster than I could blink.

```
Sub TestWithoutRE()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim srchStrings() As String
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim colsToSearch As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim allMatch As Boolean
    Dim matchArray As Variant

    'Define the strings you're looking for
    srchStrings = Split([C2], " ")

    'Define the ranges to search:
    Set colsToSearch = Range("F1:G33215")

    'Build a dictionary of the column data
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cl In colsToSearch.Cells
        allMatch = True 'this will be set to false on the first non-matching value, no worries
        'Make sure each word is in the cell's value:
        For Each s In srchStrings
            If InStr(1, LCase(cl), LCase(s)) = 0 Then
                allMatch = allMatch + 1
                Exit For  'exit this if ANY substring is not found
            End If
        Next
        If allMatch Then
            '## As long as all strings were found, add this item to the dictionary
            dict.Add cl.Address, cl.Value
        End If
    Next

    '## Here is your array of matching values:
    matchArray = dict.Items


End Sub
```

Basically I split your search parameter (`C2`) in to an array. I then iterate each cell in these columns, testing against each element of the split array from `C2`.  If any of the words from `C2` are not found then I ignore it as a partial match, you're only looking for both words matching, in no particular order.

If both words match, add the value to a dictionary object.

You can then access all matching values by referring to the `dictionary.Items` which returns an array.